# Is it possible to append some files to remote repo without local repo?

Tags: git

Let's say I don't want a local repo because It eats a lot of space on a notebook and I do only need to upload files to remote repo. I can do so by using web interface of github or gitlab.

Can I do so with a command line using git or not ?

Comment: If your problem is space, why not use a [shallow clone](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt) (so you don't get all of the history) as opposed to trying to hack around it? But I believe the short answer is: no.

Comment: You can commit changes directly on GitHub. I'm not familiar with GitLab, but I believe that's possible as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I can [upload files and have the hosting site make a new commit] using web interface of github or gitlab.

OK.

> Can I do so with a command line using git ...

No: `git somecommand` in general operates *only* on a local Git repository.  The exceptions to this, in which a command-line `git something` operates on a remote repository, are:

- `git fetch`, which brings commits from some other repository to a local repository;
- `git push`, which sends commits from a local repository to some other repository;
- `git archive --remote`, which obtains a commit from some other repository and turns it into an archive you can read locally; and
- `git ls-remote`, which sends an inquiry to some other repository so that you can see their branch and tag names (and any other names they are willing to show you) and the corresponding Git object hash IDs.

Note, however, that most systems have a `curl` command that can invoke web interface operations.  So instead of `git something` to tickle the web interface on some hosting system, consider using  `curl something`.  The *something* part will vary from one web interface to another.  Your hosting provider will usually have instructions for you.